# Where is eh_personality called?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement an OS in Rust using libcore. In the documentation, [it says that the `eh_personality` function needs to be implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/).

However, [I see no usage of this function in libcore itself](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?p=1&q=%22%23%5Blang+%3D+%22eh_personality%22%5D%22&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and I am able to compile, run, and execute panics without it.

Is there something I'm missing here? Where does `eh_personality` get called during the `panic!()` cycle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [unstable-book: lang_items](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/lang-items.html#more-about-the-language-items):

> The first of these functions, `rust_eh_personality`, is used by the failure mechanisms of the compiler. This is often mapped to GCC's personality function (see the libstd implementation for more information), but crates which do not trigger a panic can be assured that this function is never called. The language item's name is `eh_personality`.

As far as I can tell it is required to create unwind information; if you abort or loop in the `panic_fmt` language item (function `rust_begin_unwind`) it probably doesn't get called.

Also see the internal comments in [libpanic_abort/lib.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libpanic_abort/lib.rs).

If you search for [`rust_eh_personality`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?p=2&q=rust_eh_personality) you'll find a usage in [librustc_trans/context.rs: `CodegenCx::eh_personality`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9af374abf9d41c533afa46e62e1047097c190445/src/librustc_trans/context.rs#L350).  Searching for [`eh_personality`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?q=eh_personality) should reveal the places this function is called.  (It is used for code generation, not a direct call.)

Searching for `#[lang = "eh_personality"]` only shows the places where a personality is defined, not the usage.